# Mysql table lost its primary key and unique indexes after db restore

Tags: mysql, sql

A mysql table I'm dealing with used to have an auto-increment primary key as well as another unique key(not sure about that one), but doesn't anymore. I'm assuming that it is some wierd side-effect of the db was restored after a mishap(simply imported from a backup, I think).

This table had a couple of rows with the id of "0" inserted to it after the primary key broke, where I manually replaced the id to the one that it would auto increment to if it was working - to avoid losing data and tried placing 'id' as the primary key again, but I'm getting `Duplicate entry '2622' for key 'PRIMARY'` error, even though there is definitely only one row with that id(or at least that's what a SELECT shows).

What could be the cause of the bug and what would be a good way to repair it? What could be the cause of the original bug with the primary key dissapearance? Should I go back and try to fix that somehow? Please help

Edit: 
The query looking for duplicates returns :

```
2613    2
2614    2
2615    2
2618    2
2619    2
2621    3
```

(Interesting, SELECTing those ids separately only returns one result)
The other query requested in the comments returns:

```
fso_licenses_sessions   CREATE TABLE `ifso_licenses_sessions` (
 `id` int...
```

Comment: Show **CURRENT** table's DDL (execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and show the output). Execute `SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` and show the output.

Comment: *What could be the cause of the original bug with the primary key dissapearance?* Restore process firstly creates a structure without indices, then inserts data, then creates indices. In your case steps 1 and 2 were executed successfully whereas step 3 fails by some reason, I think.

Comment: You obtain partial table's DDL. You must obtain and post full DDL...

Comment: *SELECTing those ids separately only returns one result* It seems that the index is damaged. Try to restore this table one more time into some temporarily created database, and check each executed query for errors and warnings. And check system tablespace for errors also. Does the table is InnoDB, and file_per_table is enabled?